# Strange encoding on replace in file

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

I'm trying to replace 2 strings in file with this code:

```
def replace_in_file(file_path,first,second):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
        content = file.read()
    content = content.replace(first, second)
    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
        file.write(content)
```

My code does this many times and in the end I see many strange symbols, but the file is in `utf-8` encoding.
What happened?

Comment: Are you sure the original encoding is UTF-8 and not, say UTF-16 or perhaps even UCS-2?

Comment: @Doom8890 Yes, I save file with utf-8